# PowerShell How to Add to JSON Array

Tags: json, powershell

How do you add to a JSON array in PowerShell?  I'm trying with the following code, but it's complaining with a "Collection was of a fixed size" exception:

```
$json = @"
[
  {
    "name": "First"
  },
  {
    "name": "Second"
  }
]
"@

$toAdd =@"
{
  "name": "Third"
}
"@

$jobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json    
$jobj.Add((ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $toAdd))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `+=` instead of `Add()`:

```
$jobj += (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $toAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$js = @"
[
  {
    "name":"First"
  },
  {
    "name":"Second"
  }
]
"@

$toAdd = @"
[
  {
    "name":"Third"
  }
]
"@

$jobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $js
$jsrc = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $toAdd

$jobj = $jobj + $jsrc
```